# Openresty "you need to have ldconfig in your PATH env when enabling luajit"

Tags: linux, configure, openresty

I installed the latest `tar.gz` openresty file from the website, and unpacked it with `tar -xzf openresty.tar.gz`. I then did `cd` to `openresty-1.19.9.1` and typed `./configure,` and got this message:

> platform: linux (linux)

> you need to have ldconfig in your PATH env when enabling luajit.

How can I fix this? I tried looking in the `configure` file to adjust something but I'm not sure exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Install ldconfig: If you don't have ldconfig installed on your system, you can install it by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ldconfig
```

Add ldconfig to PATH: If you already have ldconfig installed on your system, you can add it to your PATH environment variable by running the following command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

This command will add /sbin to your PATH, which is where ldconfig is typically located.

After either of these steps, you can run ./configure again and it should detect ldconfig in your PATH and enable LuaJIT.